# Finding all URLs in a single line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to to fetch a page that has many urls and other stuff all in just one line in a plain text like

```
"link_url":"http://www.example.com/link1?site=web","mobile_link_url":"http://m.example.com/episode/link1?site=web" link_url":"http://www.example.com/link2?site=web","mobile_link_url":"http://m.example.com/episode/link2?site=web"
```

i tired

```
import re
import requests as req

response = req.get("http://api.example.com/?callback=jQuery112")

content = response.text
```

print content will give me the "link_url": output 
but i need to find

```
http://www.example.com/link1?site=web
http://www.example.com/link2?site=web
```

and output only link1 and link2 to a file like

```
link1
link2
link3
```

Comment: What are the data in response? It is not cleared, I am actually behind proxy, I cannot execute it myself

Comment: Is this a JSON api? Your response seems to have typos, can you give us a better example?

Comment: Hi could you please give us a clear explanation of what you want to ask with some example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below might be what you need.

```
import re

urls = '''"link_url":"http://www.example.com/link1?site=web","mobile_link_url":"http://m.example.com/episode/link1?site=web" link_url":"http://www.example.com/link2?site=web","mobile_link_url":"http://m.example.com/episode/link2?site=web"'''

links = re.findall(r'http://www[a-z/.?=:]+(link\d)+', urls)
print(links)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a string and not a JSON object, then you could do this even though it's a bit hacky:

```
s1 ="\"link_url\":\"http://www.example.com/link1?site=web\",\"mobile_link_url\":\"http://m.example.com/episode/link1?site=web\" link_url\":\"http://www.example.com/link2?site=web\",\"mobile_link_url\":\"http://m.example.com/episode/link2?site=web\""

links = [x for x in s1.replace("\":\"", "LINK_DELIM").replace("\"", "").replace(" ", ",").split(",")]

for link in links:
    print(link.split("LINK_DELIM")[1])
```

Which yields:

```
http://www.example.com/link1?site=web
http://m.example.com/episode/link1?site=web
http://www.example.com/link2?site=web
http://m.example.com/episode/link2?site=web
```

Though I think `@al76`'s answer is more elegant for this.

But if it's a JSON which looks like:

```
[
  {
    "link_url": "http://www.example.com/link1?site=web",
    "mobile_link_url": "http://m.example.com/episode/link1?site=web"
  },
  {
    "link_url": "http://www.example.com/link2?site=web",
    "mobile_link_url": "http://m.example.com/episode/link2?site=web"
  }
]
```

Then you could do something like:

```
import json
s1 = "[{ \"link_url \": \"http://www.example.com/link1?site=web \", \"mobile_link_url \": \"http://m.example.com/episode/link1?site=web \"}, { \"link_url \": \"http://www.example.com/link2?site=web \", \"mobile_link_url \": \"http://m.example.com/episode/link2?site=web \"} ]"
data = json.loads(s1)
links = [y for x in data for y in x.values()]

for link in links:
    print(link)
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a JSON api then you can use `response.json()` to get a python dictionary, as `.text` will give you the response as one long string.

You also do not need to use regex for something so simple, python comes with a url parser out of the box.

So provided your response is something like

```
[
  {
    "link_url": "http://www.example.com/link1?site=web",
    "mobile_link_url": "http://m.example.com/episode/link1?site=web"
  },
  {
    "link_url": "http://www.example.com/link2?site=web",
    "mobile_link_url": "http://m.example.com/episode/link2?site=web"
  }
]
```

(doesn't matter if IRL it's one line, as long as it's valid JSON)

You can iterate the results as a dictionary, then use urlparse to get specific components of your urls:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import requests


response = requests.get("http://api.example.com/?callback=jQuery112")

for urls in response.json():
    print(urlparse(url["link_url"]).path.rsplit('/', 1)[-1])
```

`urlparse(...).path` will return the path of your url only, eg. `episode/link1`, and we then we just get the last segment of that with `rsplit` to just get `link1`, `link2` etc.

Comment: i don think its a proper json file since its shows no JSON object could be decoded also doesnt work with JSON beautifier.  But when trying JavaScript beautifier it does work

Comment: Do you have to pass that "callback" param? Have you tried calling the api without it? Sometimes this tells the api to try to return a JSONP response rather than return raw JSON data. Just a speculation :) It would also explain why the javascript beautifier works (JSONP returns javascipt).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
urls=""" "link_url":"http://www.example.com/link1?site=web","mobile_link_url":"http://m.example.com/episode/link1?site=web" link_url":"http://www.example.com/link2?site=web","mobile_link_url":"http://m.example.com/episode/link2?site=web" """
re.findall(r'"http://www[^"]+"',urls)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
urls=""" "link_url":"http://www.example.com/link1?site=web","mobile_link_url":"http://m.example.com/episode/link1?site=web" link_url":"http://www.example.com/link2?site=web","mobile_link_url":"http://m.example.com/episode/link2?site=web" """

p = [i.split('":')[1] for i in urls.replace(' ', ",").split(",")[1:-1]]


#### Output  ####
['"http://www.example.com/link1?site=web"',
 '"http://m.example.com/episode/link1?site=web"',
 '"http://www.example.com/link2?site=web"',
 '"http://m.example.com/episode/link2?site=web"']
```

*Not as efficient as regex.